# actualizar vistas de usuarios dinamicamente PUSH JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, push

estoy realizando un mini chat y ademas necesito actualizar tablas a medida que los usuarios van utilizando el sismtema. usan informacion que van cargando y necesito que a medida que cargan se actualicen solas las tablas de todos los usuarios que las ven.
estoy usando JSF 2.2 y primefaces 7.0 con javaee 7. 
si me pueden dejar algún ejemplo.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: La versión 2.3 de JSF trae websockets out of the box. Quizás eso te permita hacer push notifications

Comment: muchas gracias disculpa la demora lo resolvi con websockets en jsf 2.2. aprendi a usarlo en el servidor. no tienen el rendimiento esperado pero sirve. muchas gracias

Comment: ya esta solucionado1